# How can I resolve the divergence of my projected gradient descent (ascent) with backtracking line search?

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent, simulation

I constructed a projected gradient descent (ascent) algorithm with backtracking line search based on the book "Convex optimization," written by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe.

The problem what I consider and the pseudocode to solve it is presented as follows:

\begin{array}{cl}
\text{maximize} & f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x_i)\\
\text{subject to} & {1_N}^T x \le c_1,\\
& x\succeq 0_N,
\end{array}
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$ is the design variable, $f_i:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a concave function with respect to $x_i$ for all $i\in\{1, 2, \ldots, N\}$, $f:\mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ is also a concave function with respect to $x$, $1_N$ is the $N$-dimensional vector with all elements equal to $1$, $0_N$ is the $N$-dimensional vector with all elements equal to $0$, and $\succeq$ represents elements-wise inequality, i.e., $i$th element of $x$ is nonnegative all $i=1, 2, \ldots, N$.

Next, the pseudocode of my program to solve the above problem is (based on Matlab grammar)

```
alpha = 0.1;
beta = 0.8;
x = zeros(N,1);
while true
    grad = find_gradient(......);  % N by 1 vector representing the gradient of f.
    y1 = get_objective(x);  % obtain the objective value for x.

    t = 1;
    while true
        x_new = x + t*grad;
        y2 = get_objective(x_new)  % obtain the objective value for x_new.
        if y2 < y1 + alpha*t*norm(grad)*norm(grad)
            t = beta*t;
        else
            break;
        end
    end

    proj_x_new = projection(x_new, c_1);   % project x_new so that the constraints are satisfied.

    if norm(proj_x_new-x) < 0.00001
        break;
    else
        x = proj_x_new;
    end
end
```

In the above code, the projection is conducted using quadratic programming function (embedded in Matlab, named "quadprog") to solve the following problem:
\begin{array}{cl}
\text{minimize} & \lVert x - x_{new} \rVert^2 \\
\text{subject to} & {1_N}^T x \le c_1,\\
& x\succeq 0_N.
\end{array}

---

In most cases, it has been confirmed in a numerical way that the above program shows a fairly good convergence speed and provides a near optimal solution.
HOWEVER, it sometimes diverge. NOT converge. As a result of checking the intermediate values of the simulation, infinite repetition occurs due to the projection process.

I really want to make my own fast gradient-based code to solve constrained convex problem.
However, my own is diverging....... What is the problem?

Comment: you project $x_{new}$ but you never project the gradient

Comment: @LinAlg Do I have to project the gradient? However, many textbooks I read just said that 1) find gradient, 2) determine step size, 3) update $x$ with projection, i.e., $x^{(n+1)} \gets Proj(x^{(n)}+\alpha\nabla f(x^{(n)}))$ for each iteration.

Comment: You should project $x_{new}$.

Comment: @copper.hat As I presented my code, $x_{new}$ is projected into the point which is closest to $x_{new}$ and located in the domain set $\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: No, you only project after you have done the step size calculation. You should project for each $t$.

Comment: @copper.hat Can I just fix `x_new = x + t*grad;` to `x_new = project(x + t*grad);` and then delete projection presented after inner `while`?

Comment: That is what I would do as a first cut.

Comment: I would also point out that you have a full simplex constraint. If you wish to get a deeper understanding of Gradient Projection it's worth understanding the projection onto the simplex yourself. First you'll need to take a piece of paper and solve the problem $P_c(\mathbf{x})=\min_{\mathbf{y}\in\Delta_n} \|y-x\|_2$. You will get an almost explicit solution, that will require some binary search. Then code that as a function that projects vectors onto the full simplex. It's a nice task.